# Seeking Help Finding A Dimmer Switch and Setting It Up

Tags: electrical, lighting, dimmer-switch

I have a 3 way light switch set up for my basement lights. I have a single light switch in the basement that controls all the lights in basement. At the top of the stairs going down to the basement is a different light switch that has one switch for the basement and another switch next to it that controls the hallway lights.

I opened up the old light switch and saw 2 black wires and 1 red hooked to the current switch, with 2 gold screws, 1 black screw and 1 green screw. 1 black wire is hooked to a golden screw, a red wire hooked to a golden screw and the other black wire hooked to a black screw, and nothing hooked to the green screw.

I bought a switch from Home Depot that had wires coming off of it and I returned since it didn't color match to what wires I have now. I found another dimmer switch that has no wires, but has 2 red screws, 1 black screw and 1 green.

Does this mean I am able to put the one black wire to a red screw, the red to the other red screw, and the remaining black wire to the black screw?

I will also post a picture of what wires I see behind the switch as well

[image: side 1]

[image: side 2]

[image: behind wall]

Comment: The dimmer switch is a switch and dimmer (two functions) You need 3 way dimmer switch (with 3 wires)

Comment: You've shown us a picture of a switch in a single-gang box. Is this the switch in the basement? Based on your description, I'd think that there would be another switch visible in the background if this were at the top of the stairs. Also in the 2nd pic, there's one black wire wrapped around the screw. Is the other black wire poked into a hole in the back of the switch (a "backstab")? Does this currently work as expected for a 3-way switch, where you can turn the lights in the basement on/off with either switch?

Comment: The wire colours and the screw colours if different are not that important.  You should have two screws the same and one a different colour.  Green screws are for ground only and only needed/wanted for your safety(not important for how the circuit works).  Do not remove wires from three ways until pictures taken and labels put on wires.  It becomes rocket science if you do not.

Comment: @FreeMan the pictures I have are from the switch in the basement. It is by itself and is for the basement lights. At the top of the stairs is a set of switches, one of which also controls the basement lights and the other switch controls the upstairs hallway.

Comment: @FreeMan the one black wire is wrapped around a gold screw, the other black wire is wrapped around a black screw.

Comment: @crip659 ok so since the one dimmer switch I found at home depot has the same setup as what I have,  just 2 red screws instead of 2 gold, I can label each wire accordingly to match and use it? (Current setup is 1 black wire to gold, 1 red to gold, 1 black to black, I can do 1 black to red, 1 red to red, and 1 black to black?) Sorry, hope I make sense with this lol

Comment: That will work.  The labels needed so the right black goes to to the right coloured screw.  Three ways do become rocket science or even quantum science if no pictures/labels before removing wires.  Always turn off the breaker before playing with wires, never trust a switch.

Comment: @crip659 ok awesome. What would a worst case scenario be if I hooked it up the exact same and something were to go wrong? Hopefully just no lights turn on from that switch...

Comment: Nothing works, only one switch works, no switches work, but lights stay on, sparks and breaker trips.  With three ways I use a book with pictures and follow it exactly when making a new circuit.  A circuit already made that I did not do/remember, I start using my fingers to flip my lips like an idiot.  One post said there is eight different ways to do them.

Comment: Wow... now that you say that I can see that black wire around the screw. It was well camouflaged! Maybe if @crip659 writes that up as an answer, it'll get a couple of up votes. ;)